# Javascript: Parsing string in csv returns NaN (not a number)

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, d3.js, nan

My csv looks like this:

```
year,dybde,snavn,sfylke
1965,110,Oslo,Sogn og Fjordane
1966,176,Krutå fjellstue,Sogn og Fjordane
1967,86,Ytre Sandsvær,Sogn og Fjordane
```

This returns NaN for the `snavn` and `sfylke` values:

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d){
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.dybde = +d.dybde;
        d.snavn = +d.snavn;
        d.sfylke = +d.sfylke;

    });

    sdata = data;

    console.log(sdata);
   });
```

I've tried putting the strings in quotes, but it still returns NaN.

Any ideas to point out the mistake would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you converting everything to numbers?

Comment: That's a good question, because I don't want to convert my strings to numbers. I didn't  know that the `+d` only worked for numbers, knowing this changes everything - thanks for putting me on the right track. I should do something like this instead:

d3.csv("example.csv", function(d) {
  return {`
    year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
    make: d.Make,
    model: d.Model,
    length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code `something = +strVar` always returns NaN - it's impossible to directly convert string to int, so it's Not a Number.

If you want to convert every string to 0, you have to write `something = strVar|0`.

Or just remove sign `+` from these lines:

```
    d.snavn = +d.snavn;
    d.sfylke = +d.sfylke;
```